# What is known about the spectrum of a general algebra?

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, banach-algebras

Whenever we have a unital algebra $A$ over a ring $R$, we may define the spectrum of an element $a \in A$ as the set of elements $r \in R$ such that $a - r e$ is not invertible, where of course $e$ is the identity of $A$. My question is: Has this object been studied in this generality? If so, I'd be grateful for a reference.

Comment: In algebra do you mean associative? commutative? Also I expect that the ground ring $R$ is assumed associative and commutative and unital?

Comment: What is the significance of writing $re$? Your definition of "algebra" allows $e$ to possibly not act as an identity on elements of $R$? If $R$ is viewed as being inside $A$, that doesn't make sense, so there is a bit of explaining to do (in addition to what was requested in the last comment.) Did you perhaps mean $ar-e$ instead?

Comment: @YCor: Of course I'm interested in theorems in each case! (Even though I didn't even think of making the ring non-unital, but it doesn't seem to invalidate the definition.)

Comment: @rschwieb I could have written $r$ instead of $re$.

Comment: @rschwieb: In your definition, an element has spectrum $R$ iff it's contained in the Jacobson radical. But that's not what I'm after.

Comment: @Cloudscape No, In my version, an element $a$ would be in the Jacobson radical iff its spectrum was *empty.* Unless "not invertible" should be "invertible"?

Comment: @rschwieb: Precisely. I just mixed up the two.